# how to use asp.net web.sitemap and menu control with bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

i am trying to use a sitemap and asp.net menu control and skin it with bootstrap.

I have done it using ul and li etc which looks great. But this doesnt add the flexibility of breadcrumbs, roles etc so i would like to use the sitemap and menu control. Anyone got any help. I cant get the toggle drop down etc to work. I have tried accesssing the item in the code behind to add css and toggle etc but it wont work.

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="MenuSitemap" SiteMapProvider="MenuSitemap" runat="server"
ShowStartingNode="false"></asp:SiteMapDataSource>
<asp:Menu ID="menFrontEnd" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="MenuSitemap"></asp:Menu>
```

**site map file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="/" title="Home"  description="Home">
      <siteMapNode url="/Default" title="Home"  description="Home" />
      <siteMapNode url="#1" title="Shop"  description="Shop">
        <siteMapNode url="/Secure/page1" title="page1"  description="page1" />
        <siteMapNode url="/Secure/page2" title="page2"  description="page2" />
      </siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url="#2" title="Maintenance"  description="Maintenance" >
        <siteMapNode url="/Secure/Maintenance/page1" title="page1"  description="Channels" />
        <siteMapNode url="/Secure/Maintenance/page2" title="page2"  description="page2" />
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented my own control based on this code and control here:

http://bootstrapfriendlywebcontrols.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V1.0/NotAClue.Web.UI.BootstrapWebControls/BootstrapMenu.cs

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Responsive ASP.NET Menu Control With Twitter Bootstrap](http://techbrij.com/responsive-menu-twitter-bootstrap-asp-net)

> In this tutorial, We will implement collapsing responsive navigation bar using ASP.NET menu control and Twitter Bootstrap.

Here is the relevant section of jQuery that is used to get the menu dropdowns to display properly.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {           
            //to fix collapse mode width issue           
            $(".nav li,.nav li a,.nav li ul").removeAttr('style');  
            //for dropdown menu           
            $(".dropdown-menu").parent().removeClass().addClass('dropdown');           
            $(".dropdown>a").removeClass().addClass('dropdown-toggle').append('<b class="caret"></b>').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');            
            //remove default click redirect effect                      
            $('.dropdown-toggle').attr('onclick', '').off('click');
        });   
    </script>
```

Note that the `.removeAttr('style')` that is used to help with collapsed mode will blow out the `Orientation="Horizontal"` property on your menu. I'm sure there is a way around this but I just haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: thanks for your help. In the end i wrote a user control that inherits the sitemap but writes out all the relivant html.

Comment: @Jonnymaboy Good news that you worked it out.  If you can, you should post your code/sulution as an answer (and self-accept it) to show others with the same problem how to fix it.

Comment: Is there any solution to this using Bootstrap 3?